# Which user has voted on my answer?

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes

Is there a way to find out which user voted on your answer or question? For anonymous users, they could just be replaced with "anonymous".

Comment: No. We use secret voting because it doesn't matter **who** voted and, personally, I don't want someone getting mad simply because I downvoted their question.

Comment: @Catija true point

Comment: "*Is there a way to find out which user voted you answer or question.*" and "*Do you know why this feature won't come out in the future?*" Have you tried searching? There are plenty of opinions about this to read already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way you can find out. And in all probability there shall be no way of this feature coming up in future too. For obvious reasons- it can easily lead to friendly voting and revenge voting if downvoted. And it's the same in real life voting too. Electoral Commissions go that extra mile to keep voter identity private.

Comment: Do you know why this feature won't come out in the future? I think this would be interesting

Comment: @RACING121 Was still updating my answer. Pls check now.

Comment: While "rage vote" and possible angry comments/heated debates is a consideration, it's more about the simple fact that voting is and should be anonymous. Why do you need to know *who* voted your post? You only need that *someone* voted.